# Pandas: how to retrieve values from a DataFrame given a list of (row, column) pairs?

Tags: pandas, performance, indexing, slice, pandas-loc

**tldr;** I want to pass a series of positions on a DataFrame and receive a series of values, If possible with a DataFrame method.

I have a Dataframe with some columns and an index

```
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame(
{'A':[0,1,3,7],
 'B':[2,3,4,5]}, index=[0,1,2,3])
```

I want to retrieve the values at specific (row, column) positions on the DataFrame

```
rows = [0, 2, 3]
cols = ['A','B','A']
```

df_a.loc[rows, cols] returns a 3x3 DataFrame

```
   |A  |B  |A
0   0   2   0
2   3   4   3
3   7   5   7
```

I want the series of values corresponding to the (row, col) values, a series of length 3

```
[0, 4, 7]
```

What is the best way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most certainly! you can use `DataFrame.lookup` to achieve exactly what you want:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html

```
import pandas as pd

df_a = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,1,3,7], 'B':[2,3,4,5]}, index=[0,1,2,3])

rows = [0, 2, 3]
cols = ['A','B','A']

values = df_a.lookup(rows, cols)

print(values)
array([0, 4, 7], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: `lookup` looks good. But I would guess it's slower than indexing under the numpy umbrella

Comment: `lookup` is Deprecated, so I suggest not to use it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas does not support that kind of indexing, only [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

```
>>> df.to_numpy()[rows, df.columns.get_indexer(cols)]
array([0, 4, 7])
```

Comment: numpy is OK, but you can face a problem if (row,col) pair do not exist

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to stack `df` and collect values with `.loc` or `.reindex`. This works if (col, row) pair is missing.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,1,3,7], 'B':[2,3,4,5]}, index=[0,1,2,3])

rows = [0, 2, 3, 100]
cols = ['A','B','A', 'C']

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([rows, cols])
values = df.stack().reindex(idx)

values
## 0    A    0.0
## 2    B    4.0
## 3    A    7.0
## 100  C    NaN
## dtype: float64
```